# Why does Rectangle.Size create new instances at every call?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, immutability

Looking into the .NET code, `Rectangle.Size` returns `new Size(Width, Height)`. Why did Microsoft choose this pattern? Personally, I would have thought that `Size` would be stored within the structure, and `Rectangle.Width`, for example, would return `Size.Width`. This would prevent a new structure from being created every property call. I'm guessing that there are some properties of immutability that influenced this decision, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Problem is, now every call to Width or Height generates a copy of the structure.  This copy can't be suppressed, a lot of the classes that have a Rectangle derive from MarshalByRefObject which prevents properties from being inlined.  Which property is used most often?  Hard to say, but the Rectangle methods themselves never use Size.

Comment: @Hans - Why does each call generate a new copy? Can't each Rectangle just have its own internal Size structure?

Comment: Assume you have a Rectangle type with an internal Size field.  Now think about how you implement the Width and Height property getters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Size` is a struct, so it's not like it's creating a new object on the heap. It will create a new copy of a `Size` value whatever you do.

I can't see that it's going to make much difference either way, to be honest. Given that the `Width` and `Height` properties of `Size` are inlined, I can see that there wouldn't be much penalty from storing a `Size` as you suggest... but equally I can see that the constructor for `Size` is so trivial that the JIT may well be able to convert the `Rectangle.Size` property to almost exactly the same native code.

So I agree it's a *slightly* odd decision, but I don't think it's going to hurt anyone much. Perhaps it makes serialization simpler or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you always get a link to the actual size you would create side effects when changing them. If your intention is to change them, you have to use the properties or getters and setters of the object you want to manipulate. If you want to use them for something else (calculating layout etc) this is the most proper solution.